# 'deviceready' is not firing when Cordova 2 is loaded in an external page in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

My Phonegap application loads a web app and the `cordova.js` file resides on the server. For example I am calling the url like "http://mydomain.com/index.php" but the `deviceready` event is not firing at all. I call the url from an internal HTML file using `window.location = url;`. I have done all the whitelisting and the page loads properly inside the app. Is there anything else I need to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug on Cordova.2.1.0. They have fixed in the 2.2.0 version but still not released. I tried the unreleased version from github and it is working fine for me.

You can download the new version from here

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap

Comment: I'm trying this in 2.4 and not getting deviceready. Any ideas?